# tailwind breakpoints affecting to all the widths

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I making a side panel and i want its width to be 90px on small screens (320px to 640px).To do this i made a custom break point on the `tailwind.config.js`. So the problem in here is that my newly made break point (320px to 640px) is affecting on all screen width size above 320px. I am using react to build the ui.

Here is my react code

```
import '/src/assets/style/sidepanel.css'
function sidepanel(){
    return(
        <>
            <div className='sidepanel sm:w-1 xs:w-[90px] float-left'>

            </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default sidepanel;
```

this is my `tailwind.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        xsss:"0px", //0 to 160px
        xss: "160px", //160 to 320
        xs: "320px", //320 to 640
        sm: "640px",
        md: "768px",
        lg: "1024px",
        xl: "1280px",
        "smm": "200px",
        'height_login': {'raw': '(max-height: 260px)'},
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    
  ],
}
```

this is my sidepanel.css

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap");
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidepanel{
    background-color: rgba(83, 19, 72, 0.85);
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I googled about this but i didnt got anything. I used tailwind arbitary values but still it didnt work out for me. I am expecting the the sidepanel width to be 90 px on small screens (320px to 640px) ie only on the applied breakpoint. I dont want the width to be 90px on large screen width ie (above 640px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xs:w-[90px] class affects all screens with a size greater than or equal to 320px. Actually, it works as : @media (min-width: 320px) { width:90px }.

There are 2 solutions to implement your idea:

1)For screens larger than 640px, consider another style, for example: **'xs:w-[90x] sm:w-[140px]'**

2)you can modify your **tailwind.config.js** as :

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'xsss': {'min': '0', 'max': '160px'},
      // => @media (min-width: 640px and max-width: 767px) { ... }

      'xss': {'min': '161', 'max': '320px'},
      // => @media (min-width: 640px and max-width: 767px) { ... }

      'xs': {'min': '321', 'max': '640px'},
      // => @media (min-width: 640px and max-width: 767px) { ... }

      'sm': {'min': '641px', 'max': '767px'},
      // => @media (min-width: 640px and max-width: 767px) { ... }

      'md': {'min': '768px', 'max': '1023px'},
      // => @media (min-width: 768px and max-width: 1023px) { ... }

      'lg': {'min': '1024px', 'max': '1279px'},
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px and max-width: 1279px) { ... }

      'xl': {'min': '1280px', 'max': '1535px'},
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px and max-width: 1535px) { ... }

      '2xl': {'min': '1536px'},
      // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }
    },
  }
}
```

so if use **'xs:w-[90px]'** ,it is applied only on screens with a size larger than **320px** and smaller equal to **640px**

Comment: Hi reza Moosavi, both the solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

TailwindCSS is mobile first. 
You have to think in the following way:
0px - 320px ---> your smaller screen value
320px-640px ---> w-[90px]
640px+ ---> your bigger screen value

So if you want to apply to TailwindCSS classes this logic, it would be someting like this: 
`"w-[smaller screen value] xs:w-[90px] sm:[bigger screen value]"`.

Comment: So you mean i should first define width for smaller screen then for mid sized screeesn and   then for large screens?

Comment: I don't think order matters since xs: and sm: actually hide @media rules. You can check this using the dev tools in your browser

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind generates `max-*` rules for this use-case : [see doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-breakpoint-range). In your case, you could use `max-xs:w-[90px]`.

However, it might be better (and closer to Tailwind's intent) to use `xs:w-[90px] sm:w-[smth]`